# Why does 'CGEL' says that 'dozens' is non-count quantificational nouns?

Tags: meaning

> From [Rodney Huddleston Geoffrey K Pullum. (2017). The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language. p.351.]
>
> We are concerned in this section with the case where **the quantificational noun** is non-count, as in *a lot of people*.
>
> [59] *dozens scores tens hundreds thousands millions billions zillions*
>
> The plural nouns in [59] are non-count in that **they cannot take numerals as dependent**; instead we have iteration of the head noun + complement construction:

Clothes can not take numerals as dependent too, but are countable nouns.

> From [Rodney Huddleston Geoffrey K Pullum. (2017). The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language. p.341.]
>
> The garment terms in [26i] denote **clothes that are** worn over the lower part of the body and cover the legs to varying degrees (or at least provide holes for them to pass through): it is of course the duality of the legs that is the source of the bipartite form of the garments.

Comment: Where exactly does CGEL state that "clothes" is a count noun in the sense given above.  You must realise that CGEL uses terms specifically and with the definitions given internally, which may not match other text books.  You can't state "Clothes" is a countable noun unless you can give a CGEL citation of the fact.

Comment: @James K Just have added the citation.

Comment: I don't see any reference to "Clothes" being a count noun in your citation. Please explain why you think that this implies that "clothes" is a count noun.  That is give the exact definition of "count noun" used in CGEL.

Comment: Your question makes no sense. CGEL explains very carefully why "dozens is a non-count quantificational noun. And it does  **not** say on p341 that "clothes is countable.

Comment: Note, "non-count" can still take plural verb forms ("clothes are"). Please edit to explain more so we know where the confusion lies.